# Putting add and remove together only in the last input

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

After each time, click on add, placed add and remove together. I do not want to have add and remove placed together. I only want remove placed besides input (remove add). Also in the last input that adding, placed add and remove together, how is it?

See: [jsFiddle - my code](http://jsfiddle.net/4BnHy/)

Comment: Your question is very unclear, to say the least. Please rewrite it and explain what you actually want and what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Wow that code is a bit of a mess. I understand what you want (Some how ..) I'll take a look. But please try to update your question if possible.

Comment: i want in latest input, placed add and remove together, and in other inputs placed only remove.

Comment: Please post your code here in addition to jsfiddle.  Once they remove your code, your questions won't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I havn't re-written your code at all. I just fixed it to do what you want, see Here: http://jsfiddle.net/4BnHy/1/.

There are much better approaches to having dynamic adding/removing. Consider having a separate add button above and separate to the inputs.

You needed to do a `.find()` inside of the newDiv and remove it.

Comment: i want in latest input, placed add and remove together, and in other inputs placed only remove.